# Routing does not work (official documentation example)

Tags: elasticsearch

As I first step I create valid index with 2 shards and routing as required:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "settings":
  {
    "index.number_of_shards": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_routing": {
      "required": true 
    }
  }
}
```

Following official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#mapping-routing-field) I'm using the sample provided there:

```
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1?routing=user1&refresh=true 
{
  "title": "This is a document"
}

GET my-index-000001/_doc/1?routing=user1
```

Above obviously works - what is not working is when I change routing value to `user2` it still gets me same document but it should not as it was indexed to route `user1` (different shard) - what I'm missing?

```
GET my-index-000001/_doc/1?routing=user2

Result:
{
  "_index": "my-index-000001",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "_seq_no": 0,
  "_primary_term": 1,
  "_routing": "user1",
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "title": "This is a document"
  }
}
```

Same for the search (I do not expect to have this document on "user2" route):

```
GET my-index-000001/_search?routing=user2
{
  "query":
  {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

Result:
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index-000001",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_routing": "user1",
        "_source": {
          "title": "This is a document"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW I know I can filter by `routing` field in the query but that is kind of workaround. I would like to have it by applying request parameter (not via modification of query) or understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have duplicate document IDs in an index

here Elasticsearch is assuming you want to update the existing document id with the new routing value and that's why you are seeing what you are seeing

Comment: With `GET` Elasticsearch is assuming that I want to update routing value? That's interesting.

Comment: I misread that sorry, you still cannot have duplicate IDs